# Unable to have kv properties reflected in python class instances

Tags: python, kivy

When I click one of the buttons, the popup that is displayed is unedited and completely lacks the information provided in the load_string. How can I get the popup class to correspond to the data provided in the load_string? How it looks: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/202ox.jpg). It should have a title and textinput widget.

EDITED: changed "Popup_Up" to "Pop_Up" in the kv language, however the issue still remains.

```
from logic import grandtotal
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty  
from kivy.lang import Builder

class Text_Input(TextInput):
    pass

class Pop_Up(Popup):
    texti_id = ObjectProperty(None)
    pass


class ShoppersApp(App, BoxLayout):
    popup_cost = ObjectProperty(Pop_Up())
    popup_people = ObjectProperty(Pop_Up())
    def build(self):
        return self

Builder.load_string("""
<Text_Input>:
    size_hint: .6, .5

<Pop_Up>:
    title: "Total Cost: "


<ShoppersApp>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: "Total Cost"
            on_release: root.popup_cost.open()
        Button:
            text: "People"
            on_release: root.popup_people.open()
        Label:
            text: "3"
""")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ShoppersApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your kv language part defines how a `<Popup_Up>:` should behave, but the python class is called `Pop_Up`. I don't know if this is a typo in your example or your actual code, but either way they need to be given the same name.

Edit: As per your typo edit fixing one thing, I think the real problem is that the lines

```
popup_cost = ObjectProperty(Pop_Up())
popup_people = ObjectProperty(Pop_Up())
```

are run (and the `Pop_Up()`s initialised) *before* the builder file is loaded. They aren't retrospecively modified by the kv language, so they never get their titles set.

It seems that just moving the load_string call to the top of the file fixes this, but I originally did so by changing the init method of ShoppersApp to dynamically create the popups as below. This may be a more generally safe/useful way to make stuff, depending on what you're doing.

```
class ShoppersApp(App, BoxLayout):
    popup_cost = ObjectProperty(Pop_Up())
    popup_people = ObjectProperty(Pop_Up())
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(ShoppersApp,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.popup_cost = Pop_Up()
        self.popup_people = Pop_Up()
    def build(self):
        return self
```

Also, having ShoppersApp subclass both app and BoxLayout makes me uneasy. It might be fine, or even proper if it's suggested in the documentation or something, but it might be safer to have separate App and ShopperLayout widgets.

Comment: Thank you for the catch, however the issue still remains.

Comment: I edited in what seems to be the real fix. Not sure if stackoverflow notifies about that.

Comment: stackoverflow didn't notify me, however thank you for the fix. I figured it didn't matter where the kv loader went, but I guess it does. I will also keep and eye on the multiple widget inheritance. Great work!

Answer (score 0):

Just call the Builder before defining the class. The following work on my machine. Kivy 1.7.0

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty  
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<Text_Input>:
    size_hint: .6, .5

<Pop_Up>:
    title: "Total Cost: "

<ShoppersApp>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: "Total Cost"
            on_release: root.popup_cost.open()
        Button:
            text: "People"
            on_release: root.popup_people.open()
        Label:
            text: "3"
""")

class Text_Input(TextInput):
    pass

class Pop_Up(Popup):
    texti_id = ObjectProperty(None)
    pass

class ShoppersApp(App, BoxLayout):
    popup_cost = ObjectProperty(Pop_Up())
    popup_people = ObjectProperty(Pop_Up())
    def build(self):
        return self

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ShoppersApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This issue has been driving me insane.